# ! CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_webrtc":

Tags: ios, flutter, windows, webrtc, codemagic

I am using Codemagic as I do not have a Mac. This is the error I get.

```
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_webrtc":
      In Podfile:
        flutter_webrtc (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_webrtc/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `flutter_webrtc (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_webrtc/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

In Flutter Windows, there is no Podfile.
How do I solve this error without using Mac?

I tried using ruby and cocoapods, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can [remote access](https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/) the Codemagic macOS machine and initialize a new file and push the changes to your repository.

Once you are connected, run these commands from the terminal. This is how you could initialize pods for example.

```
cd ios
pod init
gh auth login --with-token <YOUR_GITHUB_PAT_TOKEN>
git add .
git commit -m "Added Podfile"
git push
```

In order to push the changes to your repo, you need to authenticate yourself in your git provider. This is necessary because Codemagic only has read access to the GitHub repo. In order to authenticate with GitHub, you need to use your GitHub personal access token. See how to generate the token from https://github.com/settings/tokens.

Comment: Do I need to pay for remote access?

Comment: no, it counts as regular build minutes and for personal accounts you have 500 free minutes every month

Comment: I didn't use github. But the remote access thing was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: feel free to submit your answer and accept it. It will be very helpful to the community